# [biztalk2006]can not decode base64 to xml plain text

Tags: biztalk, biztalk2006r2

I use biz2006 + rosettaNet as our EDI solution. Now I meet a issue that, when a partner send pip to us, the content(base64 encoded) could not been converted to XML plain text.

Here're content of the pip we received.

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: application/xml; charset="UTF-8"; RNSubType=service-header`
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: 3e10e7db96b84cafbee51e66e020729f
Content-Description: body
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Attachment1"
PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz48IURPQ1RZUEUgU2VydmljZUhl
...==
```

I find a working format as below

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Anyone could tell we how to solve the issue?
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if you fixed this for yourself but I think this may help your problems:

http://biztalkmessages.vansplunteren.net/articles/dealing-with-base64/

Lots of other nice Biztalk hints and tips on there too!

Source: (Randal van Splunteren)